# Nodejs best practice with require

Tags: node.js, express

I'm learning Nodejs and express. 
I've got some pdf textbooks (and some online references) and in the examples given I always see statements like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

This can be writen in one line:

```
var app = require('express')();
```

In every textbook I look, the first method is used.

I was wondering why the second method is never used. Is this bad coding practice? Or is something else going on?

Comment: cleaner code, easier to read, easier to refactor. The second method is used plenty, just far less than the first.

Comment: Both are doing same thing. It's on your own which one you want to write.

Comment: Sometimes you have to use the veriable express for calling some method like express.static(). For those purpose its better to follow method one.

Comment: Yep, go ahead and `require('x').use('y')` inline if you never need to use the result of `require('x')` again. Also its a little cleaner to have every require statement right next to each other at the top of the file.